# How can i filter files which does not have current piece of code? Using VSC

Tags: visual-studio-code, include, reverse

i'm working with hunderts of files. Every file must include this piece of code. I know how to find files which have it included. How can i reverse it please? I use **VSC**

```
<p class="travelingRules">
  Podmínky cestování do
  <a
    href="https://www.mzv.cz/jnp/cz/encyklopedie_statu/evropa/recko/cestovani/index.html"
    title="Podmínky pro cestování do Řecka"
    target="_blank"
    ><b>Řecka</b></a
  >.
</p>
```

Comment: that is a very uncommon scenario, most of the time most files do not have what you enter in the search, and you are interested in the files that do have it. If nobody has written an extension to show this not-filter you have to write it yourself, and show a view with the files

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this search:

Find:

```
(?<!\n)^(?![\s\S]*<p class="travelingRules">
  Podmínky cestování do
  <a
    href="https://www.mzv.cz/jnp/cz/encyklopedie_statu/evropa/recko/cestovani/index.html"
    title="Podmínky pro cestování do Řecka"
    target="_blank"
    ><b>Řecka</b></a
  >.
</p>)
```

`(?<!\n)^` get the very first position in the file.

`(?![\s\S]*......` a negative lookahead that will look at every character position for the following text - you can just copy and paste your text in the search across files find input after `(?<!\n)^(?![\s\S]*`.  Only files that do not have that following text will be found.

No doubt performance is quite bad as I assume it goes character by character to see if the following is a match for your pasted text.  You will have to see if performance is a problem in your specific case.

Comment: Have you been able to test this yet?